# Java: cannot reference height before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java, subclass, abstract

I'm trying to create a class Figure with subclasses like rectangle, triangle and circle. However, when I try to compile them I get the same error in all of them, which makes me believe that the error is in the Figure class. The error: cannot reference height before supertype constructor has been called.

Figure:

```
public abstract class Figure{
    public double width;
    public double height;

    public Figure(double width, double height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract double area();

    public abstract double perimeter();
}
```

Ellipse:

```
public class Ellipse extends Figure{
    private double a;
    private double b;

    public Ellipse(){
        a = width/2;
        b = height/2;
    }

    public double area(){
        return (Math.PI * a * b);
    }

    public double perimeter(){
        return (2 * Math.PI * Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)))/2);
    }

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to call the super constructor in your base class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your constructor for Ellipse does not call the inherited constructor of Figure.  Yet you are are trying to use variables of Figure that are assigned values in the constructor of Figure.  You need to update your Ellipse constructor to call the super with values.  I recommend the following.

```
public Ellipse(int w, int h){
    super(w,h);
    a = width / 2;
    b = width / 2;
}
```

Comment: noted and fixed, thanks.  I haven't actually written java in about 10 years so I forgot that part.  Thanks.

Comment: No prob, removed my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialized you height and width, that are currently present in your Figure class. You can do this by specifically calling the Figure constructor from Ellipse, something like this.

```
public Ellipse(){
    super(23, 23);
    a = width /2;
    b = height/2;
}
```

The super() method calls your Figure constructor, which will then initialized height and weight allowing you to use them to calculate a and b accordingly.

Comment: Ah, 23! Excellent number!

Comment: Yay, random default number because I was trying to answer the question quickly. First thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need call super class constructor in Ellipse:

```
public Ellipse(){
    super(_width, _height)
    a = width/2;
    b = height/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super` as the very first thing in each constructor of every subclass of `Figure:`

```
public Ellipse(double ewidth, double eheight){
    super(ewidth, eheight);
    a = width/2;
    b = height/2;
}
```

That is necessary because you use `width` and `height`, which are a member of `Figure` and are only getting initialized when the `Figure` constructor is executed, which is what the super call does. You basically used an uninitialized variable.

So why did I call the new parameter ewidth instead of width? Would I have named them width, the fields of the same name in the parent class would have been obscured by the local variable of the same name. In your example that would not have been a problem because the code path in both constructors is dead simple, but I'd like to raise awareness for this because it is a source of obscure bugs :)

Answer (score 0):

Every class has to call the constructor of its superclass as the first instruction in each of its own constructors<sup>[1]</sup>

This is done implicitly if the superclass has a default constructor (one without parameters). But if it has only a constructor with parameters, then you have to write that call yourself. You do that by using the word `super` and passing the appropriate parameters.

This is done so that the logical part of the current class that is inherited from the superclass can properly be initialized.

You have two possible solutions:

1. Add a default constructor to `Figure`. Perhaps one with default width and height of zero:

   ```
   public Figure() {
       this( 0.0, 0.0 );
   }
   ```

   This makes sense if there is a sensible default value for the width and height.
2. Change the constructors of the subclasses so that they accept (at least) width and height as well:

   ```
   public Ellipse(double width, double height){
       super(width, height);
       a = width/2;
       b = height/2;
   }
   ```

   This makes sense if there is no sensible default for the width and height.

The way you have tried doing this, there would be no values for width and height, so you couldn't possibly use them in the subclass (e.g. `width/2` would be zero, because there was nothing that put any value in `width`, because nobody called the constructor of `Figure`). When you create an instance, there is no other place where the superclass constructor that sets `width` and `height` will be called - therefore all constructors have to start by calling their superclass constructors first.

---

[1] It's also OK to call one of the other constructors of the same class - if it has more than one - provided that ultimately, the constructor that gets called calls one of the supeclass constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has already been answered.
Refer to this:
[java call superclass from a subclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326229/java-call-superclass-from-a-subclass-constructor)

To add that if you had a non-parameterised constructor in your superclass then you wouldn't have to place an explicit call to the constructor of the superclass.

Also check this:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

There is a note on this page: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.