# Question about constructor of superclass and subclass

Tags: java

Why the the code (1) is not result an error while code (2) (3) will?

I think when the subclass calls the constructor, it will calls super class constructor first, but I do not know why the code (1) is right while other two are wrong.

//(1)

```
public class Parent {
  public int a;

  public Parent() {
    this.a = 0;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child() {}
}
```

//(2)

```
public class Parent {
  public int a;

  public Parent(int number) {
    this.a = number;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child() {}
}
```

//(3)

```
public class Parent {
  public int a;

  public Parent(int number) {
    this.a = number;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(int numb) {      
  }
}
```

Code(1) is right while other two are wrong.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `1` is right because it's well-formed Java code. `2` is wrong because the Child's constructor calls a default constructor for Parent, which doesn't exist. The same problem exists in code sample `3`.

Comment: @Avi why (2)(3) not have default constructor while (1) has?

Comment: You defined an actual constructor for the Parent in `2` and `3`. That means that the *default* constructor is replaced by the actual constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling superclass from a subclass constructor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326229/calling-superclass-from-a-subclass-constructor-in-java)

Comment: @Avi But isn't (1) also defined an actual constructor for Parent?

Comment: @Cathy Oops, that's true. In that case, you have a constructor that takes no arguments for `1`. However, no such constructor exists for `2` and `3`. I glossed over the constructor because it had no effect different than the default constructor.

Comment: This is what you need:
```
public class Parent {
  public int a;

  public Parent(int number) {
    this.a = number;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(int numb) {
    super(numb);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
>   no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not
>   have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.
>   Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
>   superclass, there is no problem.

So, here it is, your code (2)(3) doesn’t have a no-argument constructor, and also you didn’t explicitly invoke a has-argument constructor, you got a compile-time error. More details from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 1):

In code 1, the constructor for `Parent` has no arguments, so a call to the default one is implicit:

```
public Child () {
    super();
} /* This code is not necessary, but is implied. */
```

But in codes 2 and 3, the constructor has a parameter, and since there is no overload provided with no parameters, then a call to the superclass constructor *must* be provided. To do this, you must reference `super()`.

```
public class Parent {
    public int a;

    public Parent(int number) {
        this.a = number;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(int numb) {
        super(numb); // Calls Parent(int) and sets this instance’s Parent.a value to numb.
    }
}
```

Comment: *In code 1, Parent has no defined constructor* `public Parent() {
    this.a = 0;
  }`  - what do you mean?

Comment: Oops. I'll fix.