# Superclass setter method from Subclass constructor

Tags: java

I tried calling superclass public setter method from the subclass constructor and the code just works fine.
Is it ok to do so or is it considered a bad practice? What can be the problem if its bad?

***Edit***: I have an AuthFilter

```java
public class AuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    
        setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/login", "POST"));
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter has the constructor

```java
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
        
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}
```

So I am using the method `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(RequestMatcher requestMatcher)` present in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to change the login path. This works, but is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling superclass from a subclass constructor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326229/calling-superclass-from-a-subclass-constructor-in-java)

Comment: @Peter No that post doesn't answer my question. The problem there is different from this one. I have added more details in my post.